# Why do the child elements of this div not have border-radius?

Tags: css

I'm making a settings menu for one of my sites, and the `.line` divs inside it don't have `border-radius` at the top.

Here is how it looks normally:

[image: screenshot]

And when I hover over the first one (and last one) for some reason it doesn't have border-radius:

[image: screenshot2]

Here's my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #prefs_tab {
    color: black;
    background: white;
    padding: 6px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  #settings {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 10px;;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 130px;
  }
  .line {
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .line:hover {
    background: #ccc;
  }
</style>
```

And, my HTML:

```
<div id="prefs_tab">Preferences</div>
<div id="settings" style="display: none;">
  <div class="line" id="snow_off">Turn snow off</div> <!--will turn to "turn snow on" when clicked -->
  <div class="line" id="hide_bar">Hide bottom bar</div>
  <div class="line" id="music_on" style="border-bottom: 0 !important;">Turn music off</div>
</div>
```

I don't see what I am doing wrong. Is there anyway to fix this without having to add `border-radius` to both of the boxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `.line` doesn't have `border-radius` applied, and it overflows the container. Set `overflow: hidden` on the container and it will work. See http://jsfiddle.net/Xhrx8/

Comment: If I do this it will have border radius for all of the lines, though. That wouldn't look right. I thought that elements inside elements that have border-radius would automatically have border-radius?